# Mysql select sleep then return

Tags: mysql, sleep

I want select X records from database (in PHP script), then sleep 60 seconds after continue the next 60 results...

SO:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A = 'B' LIMIT 60
SELECT SLEEP(60);
....
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A = 'B' LIMIT X **where X is the next 60 results, then**
SELECT SLEEP(60);
```

AND etc...

How can I achievement this?

Comment: Why do you want to sleep for 60 seconds? You cant sleep inside mysql but you can in php/java/c#/perl etc.

Comment: i want this in a php script

Comment: See below, but you still didn't answer why you needed to delay 60 seconds.

Comment: because i have a thousands of record and i want run this script from cron...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP:

```
<?php
// obtain the database connection, there's a heap of examples on the net, assuming you're using a library like mysqlite
$offset = 0;
while (true) {
    if ($offset == 0) {
        $res = $db->query('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A = 'B' LIMIT 60');
    } else {
        $res = $db->query('SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A = 'B' LIMIT ' . $offset . ',60');
    }
    $rows = $db->fetch_assoc($res);
    sleep(60);
    if ($offset >= $some_arbitrary_number) {
        break;
    }
    $offset += 60;
}
```

What you're doing is gradually incrementing the limit field by 60 until you reach a limit. The easiest way to do it is in a control while loop using `true` for the condition and `break` when you reach your invalid condition.

Comment: Extremely dangerous answer, assuming that a SQL query will return the same result in the same order each time, with no `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Its pretty much just psuedocode I would hope thst the person asking the question would at least do some research.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "the next 60 records". SQL tables represent *unordered* sets. Without an `order by`, a SQL statement can return a result set in any order -- and even in different orders on different executions.

Hence, you first need something to guarantee the ordering . . . that is, an `order by` with keys that uniquely identify each row.

You can then use `offset/limit` to accomplish what you want. Or, you could put the code into a stored procedure and use a `while` loop. Or, you could do this on the application side.

Comment: Thats an incorrect assertion. They are ordered sets where theres a primary key auto increment field. Without it, the tables are ordered by the left most column to the right most.

Comment: i want this in a php script

Comment: @JustinMitchell . . . Can you provide the documentation reference that `select` *without* an `order by` is guaranteed to return results in a particular order.

Comment: By the primary key column in ascending order. Its in the mysql documentation.

Comment: @JustinMitchell . . . I am asking for the specific reference that as `select *` without an `order by` returns the rows in this order.  I am fully aware of what a primary key (and clustered key) are.

Comment: @JustinMitchell . . . I'm quite familiar with the reference manual.  It is not in there, as far as I know.  That is why I am asking.  There is no need to be rude.  This is a serious question.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of union http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html since those rows are unordered. But mysql data sets for non join selects are naturally ordered data sets. They're ordered by their insert id, or where thats missing, the order on disk, being the order they were added. They have to be ordered datasets otherwise the records will come out in random order every time you select. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html perhaps when you say unordered you mean a non defined sort filter, but my read is that you mean that they're unsorted, meaning random.

Comment: @JustinMitchell . . . And that documentation *explicitly* states:  "You may have noticed in the preceding examples that the result rows are displayed in no particular order. It is often easier to examine query output when the rows are sorted in some meaningful way. To sort a result, use an ORDER BY clause."  In other words, there is no default ordering of results from a `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Its natural insert order, in the absense of primary keys, which is also clearly stated in the documentation. I wonder if you have done any work with databases?

Comment: You know you're arguing about an order by component of a select statement, asserting that unless you specify an order, they're returned in random order, right? You also know that the mysql example didn't include a primary key column, which guarantees natural order by the PK column.